# How to calculate the value count in multi-value columns and visualize in bar chart?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have below csv file where values in C_DS and C_RT could  be multi-value.

```
dataCenter,C_TID,C_DS,C_RT
dcA,test_403,"performance","performanceOverallRating"
dcB,test_581,"performance","performanceOverallRating"
dcC,test_382,"performance,liveProfile","performanceOverallRating,potentialOverallRating,sysOverallPerformance,sysOverallPotential"
dcD,test_241,"performance","performanceOverallRating"
dcE,test_100,"performance","performanceOverallRating,potentialOverallRating"
dcF,test_243,"performance","performanceOverallRating"
dcH,test_282,"performance,liveProfile","performanceOverallRating,potentialOverallRating,sysOverallPerformance"
dcH,test_281,"compensation,talentFlag","finalRangePenetration,riskOfLoss"
dcK,test_1000,"compensation,performance","finalRangePenetration,objectiveOverallRating"
......
```

Now I want to count the value count in C_DS and C_RT columns, and then to visualize it in two bar charts.

Expected data transformation output are:

```
C_DS,count
performance,3
liveProfile,5
compensation,2
talentFlag,1
....


C_RT, count
performanceOverallRating,5
potentialOverallRating,7
finalRangePenetration,2
......
```

How to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way. First, calculate the unique list of labels from your column as new table.

'SampleData'
[image]

```
C_DS_label = 

VAR SplitByCharacter = ","
VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", CONCATENATEX(SampleData,SampleData[C_DS],",") ),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word])
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE(Table0,[Word])
```

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Count_C_DS = 
var curr = SELECTEDVALUE(C_DS_label[Word])
return
calculate(COUNTROWS('SampleData'), FILTER(ALL('SampleData'[C_DS]), PATHCONTAINS(SUBSTITUTE ( SampleData[C_DS], ",", "|" )  , curr) ))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi msta42a - thank you for the solution. I tried first step 'alculate the unique list of labels from your column as new table', and it is successful. when i tried second step 'create a measure' , i can't make he measure calculated successfully. please refer to my screenshot. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you provide more details? You get some error or count are incorrect? In my answer i use data from your question;

Comment: HI msta42a - no worries now, i figure it out. thank you for the help.  your solution works for me,